# How to share the user profiles with other users?

Tags: civimail, contacts, drupal-views

The requirement is if Contact A's specific field values(custom fields) are matching with Contact B field values then Contact C(Admin) should b able to share 
Contact A's profile with contact B by civimail. The profile should be of drupal view page of type Civicrm Contacts
I tried Fuzion tokens extension to attach the user id and use the link as template for civi mail-
"http://localhost/example.com/profile-page-view?uf_id={user.id}" but this will attach their own profiles(Recipients own profiles)
Admin will be finding the matching contacts using advanced search and find matches and sends email
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the custom field value as a Contextual Filter and hence only show results to B for contacts where the other contacts' custom field matches that of B. I am not quite clear on how to do this but getting the value from B and applying it as a filter on the view seems like it should be entirely feasible.

Alternatively could you consider basing this on Relationships between B and A.